# double-pane window vendors online?

Tags: windows, glass

Looking for **51.125 x 57.5 x 0.625 inch** double-pane picture-window glass,
I am getting confusing replies locally about vinyl framing, etc.

The measurements are that of window glass only, edge to edge.  The four existing aluminum beads snap out and in easily.  The aluminum frame is embedded forever in stucco, guarded fiercely by the HOA.  (There is 1/4"
play/gap between window glass and aluminum frame)

We have an aluminum frame and an HOA that allows no substitutes.
Is there an online source of plain old durable double-pane glass?

Thank you,
Gorno

Comment: What exactly are you measuring?  Just to the frame edge or did you take out the glass?  Most glass will be hidden into the frame by some amount, ~1/2 inch.  If glass needs to be cut, you want to be sure you are measuring right.  It is your money if your measurements are off/short.

Comment: The measurements are that of glass only, edge to edge.  The existing aluminum beads snap out and in easily.  The aluminum frame is embedded forever in stucco, guarded fiercely by the HOA.  (There is 1/4" of play/gap between window glass and aluminum frame)

Comment: If it’s just glass (ie, a sealed double pane unit) you’re looking for, call a real glass place and have them come and look at what you’ve got. If it’s possible to swap glass, they’ll know how.

Comment: The play/gap is important to keep.  Glass is not happy if squeezed too tight.  It seems you just need glass replacement which can be cut to size needed, instead of having to buy what a non glass(big box) store has in stock.

Comment: I've called two "glass places" here in soggy California.  One flatly refused my business for want of glaziers, and the other has me penciled in for some time next month.  As a devout DIYer, I need only fog-free glass to replace my fogged-up glass set in a very basic rectangular frame.  Sounds trivial; it isn't.

Comment: If it's any comfort, ordering new windows is taking forever, soggy California or elsewhere, so a month's wait isn't the worst thing that could happen.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search for aluminum frame windows brings up quite a few vendors and stores that sell them.

A similar search does the same for just double pane glass/windows.

Vinyl frames are the most common these days, but aluminum and wood are still available/made.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said where you are located, however in most all states in the US, there is the necessity to conform to building codes.

Because of that, HOA and Condo associations must be flexable on such rules and allow replacement of such items on your home such as door, windows, roofing and such that are as close to compliance as possible and still meet local codes without being a great financial burden to the homeowner.  Further they cannot demand that only one particular vendor be used for such repairs. Or be so strict as to make replacement or repairs unachievable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sure quite a few HOA members would like to see this.  From stories online it seems most HOA leaders do not know this.

Comment: @crip659, agreed.  Many don't know the laws regarding their own associations.

Comment: It can be even worse if you live in a house in a historic district.